# Sequence of Radon Measures $\mu_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Problem:** Find a sequence of signed Radon Measures $\mu_n$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\langle \mu_n, \phi \rangle \to 0$ for every $\phi \in C^1_c(\mathbb R)$, and $|\mu_n|([0,1]) \to +\infty$.

**Attempt:** I tried to define $\mu_n([a,b]):= \int_a^b f_n(x) dx$ with $f_n:=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ or similar. I can realize the first property or the second but not them together!

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can use a quickly oscillating sine wave whose amplitude grows (not too quickly) as $n$ grows.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I feel like I'm missing the definition of $(\mu, \phi)$. Is it $\int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) d\mu$?

Comment: Thats right. My idea was to use Riemann-Lebesgue, but grow the amplitude a little to accomplish $|\mu_n| [0,1] → ∞$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(t) = \sqrt {n}\cos (nt)\cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(t).$ Define $\mu_n (E) = \int_E f_n(t)\,dt.$ Then

$$|\mu_n|([0,1]) = \sqrt n \int_0^1 |\cos (nt)|\, dt \to \infty.$$

Let $\phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb R).$ Then

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \phi \,d\mu_n = \int_0^1 \phi(t) \sqrt n \cos (nt)\, dt.$$

On the right we can integrate by parts to get

$$\phi (1)\frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt n} - \int_0^1 \frac{\sin (nt)}{\sqrt n}\, \phi'(t)\, dt.$$

This is $0(1/\sqrt n)$ as $n\to \infty,$ so we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n=n^{3/2}\chi_{[0,1/n]}-n^{3/2n}\chi_{[1/n,2/n]}$ and $\mu_n(A)=\int_A f_n(x)dx$. Then clearly $|\mu_n|[0,1]=2n^{1/2}\to\infty$. We need to show that $\int \phi d\mu_n\to 0$ for all $\phi\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Now fix $\phi\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$. Again, since $\phi'$ is continuous and compactly supported, it is bounded. This and the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) imply that there exists a constant $C>0$ (depending only on $\phi$) such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\leq C|x-y|$.

Now we calculate
$$\int\phi d\mu_n=n^{3/2}\left(\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)dt-\int_{1/n}^{2/n}\phi(t)dt\right)$$

Let's look at the first term:

$$\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)dt=\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)-\phi(1/n)dt+\frac{\phi(1/n)}{n}$$
and to deal with the first term in the RHS,
$$\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)-\phi(1/n)dt\leq\int_0^{1/n}|t-1/n|Cdt\leq\int_0^{1/n}C\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2C}{n^2}$$
In simpler terms,
$$\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)dt=\frac{\phi(1/n)}{n}\pm\frac{2C}{n^2}$$
The same arguments show that
$$\int_{1/n}^{2/n}\phi(t)dt=\frac{\phi(1/n)}{n}\pm\frac{2C}{n^2}$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int\phi d\mu_n\right|&=n^{3/2}\left|\int_0^{1/n}\phi(t)dt-\int_{1/n}^{2/n}\phi(t)dt\right|\leq n^{3/2}\frac{4C}{n^2}=\frac{4C}{n^{1/2}}
\end{align*}
which goes to $0$.

Comment: That seems great! Is the first $|\mu_n|=2n^{1/2}$??

Comment: @Maffred Yes! Thanks for pointing that out.